# AVAudioSession not respecting silent switch when using head phones

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, avaudiosessioncategory

I am trying to use `AVAudioSession` and `AVAudioPlayer` to play a short sound in an app, but only when the silent mode is not on. Using the `.ambient` category seems to be doing this as expected. But when I am using AirPods (or any other ear phones) it plays the sound anyway.

```swift
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient)
```

Does anyone know how I can get it to respect the silent switch also when using ear phones?

I would expect a way to get the `AVAudioSession` to respect the silent mode, also when using ear phones.